# jquery-ui , how to revert the cursor back to default

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

In my `jquery-ui` I have `draggable` and `droppable` elements. In `draggable` I have put

```
revert: "invalid",
```

And made `childspan` class as `droppable`,

```
$('.childspan').droppable({
        greedy: true,
        hoverClass: "droppable-in", 
        over: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).css("cursor", "no-drop");
            $(ui.helper).empty();           
        },
        out: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).css("cursor", "default");
            $(ui.helper).append(myimg);         
        },      
    });
```

Things are fine but the problem is , when i drag item over `childspan` `droppable`, it changes the cursor to `no-drop` and when I leave mouse it reverts as expected. But the cursor does not change back to `default`.

**Please help how to revert cursor back to default in revert.**

Answer (score 0):

Using your `over` and `out`, I would add and remove a class so that you can control the cursor via CSS instead of via `.css()`.

```
$('.childspan').droppable({
  greedy: true,
  hoverClass: "droppable-in", 
  over: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).addClass("no-drop-cursor");
    $(ui.helper).empty();           
  },
  out: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).removeClass("no-drop-cursor");
    $(ui.helper).append(myimg);         
  }
});
```

If you cannot do this for some reason, I would use `inherit` or `auto` instead.

```
$(this).css("cursor", "auto");
```

Also, this will depend on which event is still being called. `out` says:

> Triggered when an accepted draggable is dragged out of the droppable (based on the `tolerance` option).<sup>1</sup>

If you're still dragging over a drop zone, `over` is still being triggered.

Also remember this:

> *Note: The ui object is empty but included for consistency with other events.*<sup>1</sup>

This means that `$(ui.helper)` does not contain an object and cannot be appended to. Are you seeing an error in console for this?

<sup>1</sup> [Droppable Widget API](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-out)

Comment: Hi @Twisty. I am dragging over drop zone, which is not droppable for this item and leaving the mouse click there itself. So technically i am not in "out". So how the class/cursor will change. I think we should handle this in draggable "revert" only.

Comment: @sand it's hard to understand what actions are taking place. If I understand, you are dragging an item and then dropping it to a location. If the item should not be dropped there, then `revert` from draggable should be used or `false` should be return from `drop` callback. `out` is only called when the item is still being dragged.